# How can I read the content of a .pfx file in Java?

Tags: java, pkcs#12

I have `file.pfx` file and also have a private key. How can I read the certificate in `file.pfx` in Java?

I have used this code:

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.security.auth.callback.*;
//These packages I have used.

public String readFile(String fn) { 
  String thisLine, ret = ""; 
  KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "SunJSSE"); 
  ks.load(new FileInputStream(fn),"password".toCharArray()); 
  try { 
    Key key = ks.getKey("1", "password".toCharArray());
    Certificate[] cc = ks.getCertificateChain("1");
    X509Certificate certificate1 = (X509Certificate) cc[0];//Here it throws  java.lang.NullPointerException 
    ret += certificate1.getNotAfter(); 
    ret += certificate1.getNotBefore(); 
  } catch(Exception e) { 
    ret = "Cannot load, exception!";
  } 
  return ret; 
}
```

Comment: What does "*line by line*" mean? Are you wanting to read certificates from the PFX file? What have you tried so far?

Comment: In future, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15130548/edit) to include that information. It's useless and unreadable as a comment.

Comment: Ok, so you've shared your code. What's wrong with it - does it not work?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It shows worning "X509Certificate" can not find symbol. I have import tha pachage import java.security.*;

Comment: `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` is a part of the core Java libraries. If you are programming in an IDE, this should have been imported automatically.

Comment: Hello Duncan Jones: program compile fine but throws exception  X509Certificate certificate1 = (X509Certificate) cc[0]; in this line. can please help out.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15130548/edit) and include the full stacktrace of your exception. Without this, we cannot help you. Remember, we *only* know what you post in your questoin!

Comment: I got the exception java.lang.NullPointerException. Do you want me to write the full code in the question?

Comment: Are you sure the alias is actually "1"? I'd suggest you iterate over the aliases within your keystore and figure out the proper alias.

Comment: Where you determine the alias to 1?

Answer (score 8):

Try This Code for Reading .pfx file:-

```
  public void checkExpire() {

        try {
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            char[] password= "yourfilepassword".toCharArray();

            keystore.load(new FileInputStream("filepath\filename.pfx"),password);
            //keystore.load(new FileInputStream(certificate), password);
            kmf.init(keystore, psswd);
            Enumeration<String> aliases = keystore.aliases();
            while(aliases.hasMoreElements()){
                String alias = aliases.nextElement();
                if(keystore.getCertificate(alias).getType().equals("X.509")){
                Date expDate = ((X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificate(alias)).getNotAfter();
                Date fromDate= ((X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificate(alias)).getNotBefore();
        System.out.println("Expiray Date:-"+expDate );
        System.out.println("From Date:-"+fromDate);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You are getting an exception because your keystore (i.e. the PKCS #12 file) does not contain a certificate chain with the alias you have provided.

```
Key key = ks.getKey("1", "shalimar1234".toCharArray());
Certificate[] cc = ks.getCertificateChain("1"); // this is returning null
```

It's quite plausible your `key` object is `null` too, but you don't appear to use the object at all.

To understand what aliases are available in your file, trying looking at the strings returned from [`KeyStore.aliases()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#aliases%28%29).

Comment: Thanks it works. I use alises. I use the code like: String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
   Key key = ks.getKey(alias, "shalimar1234".toCharArray());
   Certificate[] cc = ks.getCertificateChain(alias); Then it works fine. Can you please tell me how can I read the whole content of the certificate.

Comment: @Banshi It sounds like we've solved this particular problem. If you have further problems, please try and research a solution yourself. If you cannot find one, then please post a new question.

Comment: ok. Thanks. I am also searching for these problem. Actually I am fresher in java. I am PHP developer and iPhone developer. I have a recent project in php which have a requirement that there will a .pfx file in a removable drive and if the file exist in the removable drive the login panel will open. For these reason I have to use applet I have solve these problem with a file.txt file but I never work on file.pfx file system. That is why I post these question. And you accompany me for a long time. If I have to post a question for every query these will be a laborious task. Thanks a lot. lol.:)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/585238/java/java/extract-private-key-pfx-PKCS) to a forum question on the subject of opening and reading a .PFX file using Java code.

To summarize what's in the link, you should be able to open the Key-store as you would with a normal JKS, but with a slight difference, pass the Key-store type as `pcks12` and the provider as `SunJSSE`.

```
try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("C:/store.pfx")) {
    KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "SunJSSE");
    store.load(stream, "password".toCharArray());

    Enumeration<String> aliases = store.aliases();

    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.err.println(aliases.nextElement());
    }

    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)store.getCertificate("alias");
    System.err.println(certificate.getNotAfter());
    System.err.println(certificate.getNotBefore());
    System.err.println(certificate.toString());
}
```

Another helpful note is that you might wanna consider using and referring to the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) Provider, it is the most complete implementation out there in my humble opinion.

Comment: I haven't tried this before, here's a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) regarding the SunJSSE provider.. I would highly recommend you look into using [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) as a JCE provider by the way.

Comment: Link-only answers are not very helpful on StackOverflow. If your link were to break in the future, your answer becomes meaningless. Can you summarise the link contents in your answer please?

Comment: using System.err.println(certificate.toString()); get encoded worlds. How can i get only contents of the certificate.